# how to use sql NOW( ) function in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have used sql's `now()` function several times in normal query in php db connectivity...

But in laravel it does not displays anything and also the data is not inserted

the code I am using is:

```
$exercise = Exercise::insert(
                    array(  'fk_users_id'       => '1',
                            'fk_equipments_id'  => $equipment,
                            'muscular_group'    => $muscular,
                            'exercise_name'     => $postedContent['exercise_name'],
                            'exercise_type'     => $postedContent['type'],
                            'Status'            => '1',
                            'DateCreated'       => 'NOW( )',
                            'DateModified'      => 'NOW( )')
                    );
```

it stores the data into the database but the time in not stored in any of the columns

at first my method was:

```
$exerciseDetails    = Input::all();         
$exercise           = Exercise::create($exerciseDetails);
```

the above method updates date and time itself and worked fine for other controllers but now **I am having a problem of having a check box checked array in my post so it throws error**

is there any other method in laravel to do this ??

Comment: You would be better suited using [Eloquent's timestamping feature](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps) to do this for you automatically

Comment: why not using php `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`?

Comment: Doctrine2 uses `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @sgt why to use an extra php function instead of a single in built query function bro?? or is that an effective way ahead of `now( )` ?? i dont know..

Answer (score 4):

Laravel comes with created_at and updated_at timestamp fields by default, which it keeps updated by itself.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps

Answer (score 1):

```
$now = DB::raw('NOW()');
```

$now variable can use in insert like

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = $name;
$user->created_at = $now;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this
`Carbon::now()` instead 'NOW( )'
or use  `DB::raw('NOW()')` instead 'NOW()'

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking **to direct query** to get **MySQL** DB **current Time**.

You can go like this;

```
$currentDBtime = DB::select( 'select NOW() as the_time' );
$currentDBtime[0]->the_time;
```